# Passing simple POJO to Javascript using htmlunit

Tags: java, javascript, rhino, htmlunit

I'm trying to render a html by passing a simple POJO as a parameter to the javascript method using htmlunit. I'm not able to find any clear example on this.

I'm using the following java code
TestMain.java

```
public class TestMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3);
    webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            POJO pojo = new POJO();
            pojo.setName("POJO here");                               
        HtmlPage page = null;
    try {                        
              page = webClient.getPage("file:////c://pojo_pass.html");
              page.executeJavaScript("show(" + pojo + ")");                       
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }          
   }

}
```

Here is the html(pojo_pass.html) it is trying to open

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show(pojo) {
        $("#pojo_div").text(pojo.getName());
    }       
</script>
  </head>
   <body>
Text: <div id="pojo_div"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to pass a simple pojo Object (getter and setter) it doesn't work.

POJO.java

```
public class POJO{
  public String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name= name;
  }

}
```

I would like to know how to pass an object in Java to the Javascript method.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has no concept of JavaBeans.

You need to pass something JavaScript understands: a marshalled bean (e.g., JSON), strings, etc.

Comment: Bindings in javax.script allows us to do Java object to javascript object mapping. I'm dealing with a dom here so wondering how to do using htmlunit

Comment: @Prabhu Yeah. If you were running that as something other than a web page, maybe. But you're not. You're not running the web page's JavaScript via a script engine hooked up to your current context.

Comment: But I believe htmlunit's script engine(rhino) can do it. I just want to know how.

Comment: @Prabhu You'd need to hack HtmlUnit fairly significantly, AFAIK, tie in the page's JavaScript context to your app's context, and figure out how to seamlessly combine the default context with your own. Good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks for the input.I guess it won't require much of a hack. I did a thorough search on the htmlunit (core-js) api and [net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit-core-js/2.8/htmlunit-core-js-2.8-javadoc.jar!/index.html?net/sourceforge/htmlunit/corejs/javascript/NativeJavaObject.html)  might do the trick. . I will post the output once I'm able to achieve it.